# Dynamic checkbox generation in android

Tags: android, checkbox, android-xml

I need to generate two reference checkboxes(that i put already in the xml given below) for two different objects.one checkbox reference(from one checkbox can generate based on the number of objects) is worked fine but for the second checkbox it is showing right to the first one...Using that single refrence(id given for a checkbox) i can create a lot of checkboxes dynamically...it is also working fine....but the  second checkboxes must have to show under the first one's created...but it is showing right side to the screen and right side to first ones.Can anyone please help.....

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="horizontal" 
    android:background="#4D000000"
    >
    <TableRow
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:gravity="center_horizontal">

    <CheckBox
        android:id="@+id/checkBox1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:text="CheckBox" />
    </TableRow>

    <TableRow 
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:gravity="center_horizontal">
    <CheckBox
        android:id="@+id/checkBox2"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:text="CheckBox" />
    </TableRow>
    </LinearLayout>
```

Here is my new xml...

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" 
    android:background="#4D000000"
    >
    <LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" 
    android:background="#4D000000"
    >
<RelativeLayout 
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" 
    android:background="#4D000000"
    >
    <CheckBox
        android:id="@+id/checkBox1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:text="CheckBox" />
    </RelativeLayout>



  </LinearLayout>
<CheckBox
        android:id="@+id/checkBox2"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:text="CheckBox" />
</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: You're working with a linearlayout in horizontal orientation. So therefore, each element you add are (by default) placed at the right of the previous.
One easy way would be to change your LinearLayout to a RelativeLayout to access more placement options

Comment: But it is not working @Nicolas Simon...It is just overriding...

Comment: First, Change android:orientation="horizontal"  to vertical.

Comment: yeah i removed...but no special changes

Comment: as @Josh said change orientation and save and clean your project and then run it again

Comment: @karan after displaying the first objects checkboxes(dynamically created),only the second objects checkboes have to generate but now it is generating alternatively.......

Comment: not getting what you are trying to say, better show some image, wld be of great help